# csproj file settings for several build projects

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have this solution structute:

```
Solution.sln
  |--WebUI.csproj (has Core.csproj as dependency)
  |--Core.csproj
  |--Tests
      |--UnitTests
          |--WebUI.UnitTest.csproj (has Core.csproj and WebUI.csproj as dependencies)
          |--Core.UnitTest.csproj (has Core.csproj as dependency)
```

What should I add to WebUI.csproj to build WebUI.UnitTest.csproj and Core.UnitTest.csproj all together? (in my WebUI\bin folder I need these libs: WebUI.UnitTest.dll and Core.UnitTest.dll).

Thanks!

Comment: If you build the solution, WebUI.UnitTest.csproj and Core.UnitTest.csproj should get built already. Why do you want them to build from within WebUI.csproj? (if that is what you want, I'm not sure if i even understand the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct method is that add WebUI.UnitTest project and Core.UnitTest project as dependencies for WebUI project. But the WebUI.UnitTest project already has WebUI.csproj as dependencies, this method does not work in your solution structure. If you just want to have WebUI.UnitTest.dll and Core.UnitTest.dll in your WebUI\bin folder, you can add a task in your WebUI.csproj to copy those files to the folder:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

<PropertyGroup>  
  <SolutionDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</SolutionDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\WebUI.UnitTest\WebUI.UnitTest.csproj&quot;" />
<Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\Core.UnitTest\Core.UnitTest.csproj&quot;" />

<PropertyGroup> 
  <CopyFileOutput>$(SolutionDir)\WebUI.UnitTest\bin\Debug\WebUI.UnitTest.dll;$(SolutionDir)\Core.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Core.UnitTest.dll</CopyFileOutput>
</PropertyGroup>



<Copy  
  SourceFiles="$(CopyFileOutput)"  
  DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)\WebUI\bin"  
/>
```

**Note that**: The stijn`s comment is right, *you build the solution, WebUI.UnitTest.csproj and Core.UnitTest.csproj should get built already.*

I have also added build steps of WebUI.UnitTest.csproj and Core.UnitTest.csproj in the WebUI.csproj so that you just only need to build the WebUI.csproj.